# how to manually set order status to "Complete"?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, order-status

I created an invoice for an order, then created a shipment from my magento admin and I encountered a rare problem, for some reason when I pressed "Submit Shipment" the website went to a 404 page, server side issues, being looked at separately. Now the order has an invoice and shipment, literally the order is complete but the status still remains as processing. when I check the invoices tab, the invoice is there, when I check shipment tab the shipment is there. has anyone else ever encountered this?
I believe when the system crashed it recorded the shipment however didn't change the status to "Complete" So is there a way to manually change the status to "Complete"? Perhaps from the database?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following SQL queries should set an orders status

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'complete';  
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state = 'complete', status = 'complete';
```

Of course, if you wanted to update specific records, you'd add WHERE entity_id = '1245' or whatever to the end of the query. 
**OR**

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET state = 'completed', status = 'completed' WHERE increment_id IN (order#1,order#2,etc);

UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = 'completed' WHERE increment_id IN (order#1,order#2,etc);
```

And always backup the database before you run any queries like the above!

Comment: thank you, I was able to manually edit the order statuses with your first method.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to modify the status on a Magento 2 instance the tables have changed. **sales_flat_order_grid** is now **sales_order_grid** and **sales_flat_order** is now **sales_order**

Comment: Not an answer ... question was tag with `magento-1.9`

Comment: please check the version it belongs to magento-1 but answer belongs to magento-2